# Show Dialog with WebBrowser

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control, printdialog

I want to show a printer dialog but when I run the following code, it prints right away while the ShowPrinterDialog is open.  In other words, it doesn't wait for the ShowPrinterDialog to close before printing.

```
WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
browser.DocumentText = "<b>Stack Overflow FTW!</b>";
browser.DocumentCompleted += Browser_DocumentCompleted;

void Browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    ((WebBrowser)sender).ShowPrinterDialog();
    ((WebBrowser)sender).Print();
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the last line with .Print() ;-)

Answer (score 0):

- If you don't use `WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs`, declare it just as `EventArgs`
- Don't cast more then once

i.e.:

```
void Browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     WebBrowser browser = (WebBrowser)sender;
     browser.ShowPrinterDialog();
     browser.Print();
}
```